# Why has the Appcelerator / Titanium reverse geocoding suddenly stopped working?

Tags: geolocation, titanium, appcelerator, reverse-geocoding

I have an app out the app store which uses the [reverseGeocoder method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-reverseGeocoder) from Titanium's Geolocation class to resolve a location to an address.

I has been working fine until this weekend where it has been giving me this error from the event object:

> error reverse geocoding

Why is this happening? Has Appcelerator changed something that I have missed? I can't find anything like that.

Here is my code:

```
Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder(e.coords.latitude, e.coords.longitude, function (e) {
    if (e.error) {
        console.log('GPS reverseGeocoder Error' + e.error);
        alert(L("location_services_error"));   
        activityIndicator.hide();
        return;
    }
    if (e.places) {
        activityIndicator.hide();
        var p = e.places[0];
        $.location.height = Ti.UI.SIZE;
        $.location.value = p.street + ", " + p.city + ", " + p.country;
        $.location.height = Ti.UI.SIZE;
        $.locationLabel.hide();
    } else {
        alert(L("location_services_not_found"));
        activityIndicator.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [error code value](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/ReverseGeocodeResponse-property-code) with one of possible values in [Titanium.Geolocation namespace](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-property-ERROR_DENIED). This will give you more insight what went wrong.

Comment: The error code I got back was "-1". What does that mean?